# AWS ec2 instance: React fetch data from PHP, getting error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: php, reactjs, connection-timeout

I use React for frontend and PHP for backend, and I am making a calendar where users can login and manage their events. Currently, the availableEvents.js is intended to access all events associated with the current user; if the user is not logged in, it would return that the user does not have access to the content. The AccessEvents.php is the backend stuff, and I assume the database.php used to access MySQL database is correct. But my React sends a request to backend, it says that

```
AvailableEvents.js:11 
 POST http://ec2...com:8000/backend/AccessEvents.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Can anyone help if there is any issue in the code?
If there is no, then is it the problem of database? probably the access to database?

```
// AvailableEvents.js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEvents = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://ec2...com:8000/backend/AccessEvents.php', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            day: currentDate.getDate(),
            month: currentDate.getMonth() + 1, // Month is zero-based, so we add 1
            year: currentDate.getFullYear(),
          }),
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setEventList(data.events); // the server responds with an array of events
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching events:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchEvents();
  }, [currentDate]); // Trigger fetchEvents when currentDate changes
```

```
// AccessEvents.php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
session_start();
require 'database.php';
if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) && isset($_SESSION["id"])){
    // if the user is logged in
    // provide buttons that enable the user to perform different actions
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    $userID = $_SESSION['id'];
    $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
    //This will store the data into an associative array
    $json_obj = json_decode($json_str, true);
    $day = $json_obj['day'];
    $month = $json_obj['month'];
    $year = $json_obj['year'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE creator = ? AND day = ? AND month = ? AND year = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $userID, $day, $month, $year);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    // access all the events by executing 
    $events = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $events[] = $row;
    }

    // Return JSON response with the fetched events
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(['events' => $events]);
} else {
    // Handle unauthorized access or other errors
    http_response_code(401); // Unauthorized
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Unauthorized']);
}
?>
```

I have tried setting headers, using different domains, and
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
in the http.conf in the aws ec2 instance.
If there is anything that I should undone, please let me know.

Comment: have you tried to just run some basic code to test if backend works? or connects?

Comment: `I have tried setting headers, using different domains, and Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin`...none of these have any relevance. It's a timeout issue - so it's certainly unrelated to CORS headers (it's unclear why you thought adding CORS headers was useful, other than just as some random guesswork), and in fact probably the request is never even reaching the server in the first place - have you checked the server's logs to see if it's got a record of these requests? Can you access any other PHP scripts on that server via a similar URL?

Comment: yeah, I have tried some basic codes (e.g. just return some sinmple json files without access). but the server is not working. Could anyone explain it to me?

Comment: Oh you are right, I just checked the server's logs, and it never receives any requests. How should I fix that?

Comment: It could be a firewall issue, DNS issue (although usually that gives a specific error), or other network problem which is blocking the connection to that server on that port. It's not a code problem. Also are you sure the correct protocol is `http`, and not `https`?

Comment: I just the check the connection, it is http, not https. After fixing the connection issue, the request was indeed sent to the server. However, I get another issue: [Mon Mar 18 16:03:02 2024] ... [404]: /backend/Register.php - No such file or directory
I dont know how to fix this one

Comment: My file structure looks like this:
- project
   (- backend
        (- Register.php)
        (- AccessEvents.php)
 )
   (- frontend (react)
      (- src
          (- components
               (- Register.js)
               (- AvailableEvents.js)
           )
      )
   )

Comment: Well we don't know what the server's website root is set to, you should check the server config. Maybe the URL should be /project/backend/Register.php - but that's just a guess

Comment: Is there way that we can check the server's website root? Idk how to check the server config. I am a newbie to full stack app.

Comment: Is the server using Apache to serve the pages? If so, check the Apache config. If it's nginx, or IIS, or whatever check the configs of those products accordingly.

Comment: it is the apache. How do I check the apache config?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to use a search engine? https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+check+the+apache+site+root+ec2